# mysql using max and distinct for 2 column in 2 tabs

Tags: mysql, tabs, max, distinct

I want for each projet to have the highest reach of etape.

```
select nometape, description
from etape
where idetape in(
select max(idetape) from etapexprojet)
where distinct(idprojet));
```

my tab look like

```
etape
idetape/nometape/description
1/debut/commencement
2/rédaction/avancement
3/fin/fin

etapexprojet
idetape/idprojet
1/1
2/1
1/2
2/2
3/2
1/3
```

I got an error on the line 5 but i don'T know how to overcome it

Comment: And your error is? And your line 5 is? Also forma the code so it is readable.

Comment: Somebody help me please